# S3TransferManager AWS JAVA SDk V 2.X downloadDirectory() method downloading objects with wrong file name

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, awss3transfermanager

I am using JAVA 1.8 and S3TransferManager(Java SDK V2.X) to download all objects from S3 bucket and i am using

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>s3-transfer-manager</artifactId>
  <version>2.17.247-PREVIEW</version>
</dependency>
```

Code appears as below
...

```
           S3TransferManager s3TransferManager = S3TransferManager.create();

           DirectoryDownload directoryDownload = s3TransferManager
                        .downloadDirectory(DownloadDirectoryRequest.builder()
                        .destinationDirectory(Paths.get("/home/shashank/Documents"))
                        .bucket(bucketName)
                        .prefix(bucketPath)
                        .build());

        // Wait for the transfer to complete
        CompletedDirectoryDownload completedDirectoryDownload = directoryDownload.completionFuture().join();

        // Print out the failed downloads
        completedDirectoryDownload.failedTransfers().forEach(System.out::println);
```

...

This code is downloading all files from S3 but omitting first charater from file name.

Ex : Download files are renamed to
**mage.jpg and itle.png**
Actual objects in S3 were
**image.jpg and title.png**

Please guide me if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Bug reported for this : https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/3366